# Getting errors on redirect only from certain pages

Tags: asp.net

I have a menu in my Site.Master file whose code is as follows;

```
<nav>
    <ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
        <li class="topfirst"><a href="Default.aspx"><span>Home</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="../Account/Login.aspx">Employee Login</a></li>
               <li><a href="../Account/Login.aspx">Customer/Distributor Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="topmenu"><a href="#"><span>Products</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Page1.aspx">Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="Page2.aspx">Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="Page3.aspx">Page3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="topmenu"><a href="InvestorInfo.aspx"><span>Investor Info</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="InvestorInfo.aspx">Quarterly Filings</a></li>
                <li><a href="InvestorInfo.aspx">Press Releases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Investor Updates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Company Presentations</a></li>
                <li><a href="BioPages/ManagementTeam.aspx">Management Team</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When I go to the sites login page BUT do not login and try to go to any of the links in the menu I get a 404 error page which says I'm trying to redirect to /Account/Page1.aspx.

Why is the "Account/" getting inserted into that path when the path from the Site.Master is clearly only Page1.aspx. I've tried changing the href to `~/` and `../` infront of the page name but that produced different types of errors ALTHOUGH it did properly redirect ONLY when in the login page (which is in the Account folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was far easier, and much more practical solution to use Page.ResolveURL("~/Account/Login.aspx"). I used Page.ResolveURL for all the links in the menu and now it works seamlessly

Answer (score 1):

Better practice to use the tilde symbol instead of a relative path but with this you will need to use the

```
runat="server"
```

in the tag.
what were the other errors you got with that approach?

edit

```
<li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login.aspx">Employee Login</a></li>
```

Comment: for example, when changing the path in the href tag to ../Page1.aspx (done for all of them) once in the login page BUT not logged in it DOES direct you to the Page1.aspx but then when you try to navigate to any other page from that menu you get the 404 error again. Where do you put the runat="server", in the nav tag or each li tag?

Answer (score 1):

When you access Login.aspx page It will in 'Account' Folder directory. When you try to access other links in menu, it will first check in current 'Account' directory if page is exist it will display page otherwise it throws error.

I suggest you require dynamic menu for this. when You access 'Account' directory page it will change the menu as per the 'Account' directory and link.

You can use literal control and Literal1.Text = 'HTML Menu Code'